# TFS 2013: Uploading new report

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

We have a fully working TFS 2013 and have access to the default reports of the process template that we are using. Now we created a new report and try to make it appear in the team explorer of VS2013. Searching the internet indicated that the only possible option would be to download the process template, change the reporting part (e.g. adding the new report as default report) and then upload the "default" reports then via command line tool (tfpt addprojectreports ...)
Since changing (including adding) areas, iterations and other stuff can be done in the "live" system (without editing the process TEMPLATE), it is hard for me to believe that there is no way to add reports without changing the process template.
Does anyone know how to upload a new report? Of course, in the end we would like to see the report in the team explorer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try http://yourReportingServer/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
then navigate via collection, project to the folder you want the report to show up in, then "upload file".

Answer (score 0):

You can directly upload the .rdl file to SSRS of your TFS instance.